# Get records from the week until the given date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How can i get records in SQL Server 2005. Input will be a weekday Date. Output should be all the records from that week before that date. For Example, If i give a Wednesday Date, i should get all the records from Monday until Wednesday of that week.

I have tried this to get all the records in a specific week when a weekday is given as input. But i want records until the given day from Monday.

```
where RD.Date > DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Date)-1), @Date) and RD.Date < DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @Date)), @Date)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
 WHERE RD.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@Date), 0) AND @Date
```

I know in SQL Server, BETWEEN forces an inclusive search, so you can do a > and < against RD.DATE

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
...
WHERE RD.Date >= DATEADD(dd, (-1) * (DATEPART(dw, @Date) - 1), @Date)
AND   RD.Date < DATEADD(dd, 1, @Date) -- inclusive
```

`DATEPART(dw, @Date)` returns the day-number in the week, so for wednesday it returns 3. But since you want to include the monday i needed to subtract 1.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) according to the comment of Lamak:

> When datepart is week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw), the return value
>   depends on the value that is set by using SET DATEFIRST.

Comment: It returns 3 depending on the setting of `DATEFIRST`, it isn't an absolute value

Comment: @Lamak: Thanks. Edited my answer accordingly.